Is it possible to directly measure Lorentz length contraction?
Could one design an accelerator ring, which constructs a packet of charges, in roughly cylindrical shape, then accelerate it around the ring, and measure its length contraction?
That is, we wish to test a prediction of special relativity: a moving object contracts in the direction of motion.  Has anyone ever proposed an experiment, whereby a rod is accelerated to high speed, and its length measured in the observer's (lab) frame?
A theory cannot be considered valid, until its empirical predictions have been verified.  In particular, "what the muon sees in its frame" doesn't satisfy this condition, in fact this common argument is a logical fallacy.

Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrocyclotron

This question is similar to: Proof of Lorentz contraction?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Re your edit: if your "rod" is a nucleus then this is exactly what the RHIC experiment has measured as described in my answer to the linked question.
